# Installing matlab, input boxes greyed out

Tags: matlab

I am trying to install matlab R2021A on 21.04 but the typing input behaves weirdly.

I run sudo ./install and the install client pops up.
Here I have the problem that I can type straight away but if I click on the window I can no longer type into the input box. This becomes a problem when I have to enter the login name later on and the cursor is not automatically in the right box and so I am stuck not being able to click on next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply alt + tab ing away and back again lets me type in the field. By clicking on the field before alt tabbing I can choose the field the cursor will be in when I come back.